# Creating a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Ok, so I am currently trying to create a binary search tree, with each node containing a reference to some object, as well as a reference to its left child and a reference to its right child (3 variables in all). The left child has to always be smaller than its parent, and the right child always has to be larger than its parent. I have to create two methods: 1 method ( contains()) to check if an element is in the tree, and an add() method to add an element to its appropriate place in there tree.

Here is the BinarySearchTree class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree {

public BinarySearchTree(TreeNode t){
    super(t);
}

public boolean contains (Comparable obj){
    if (this.myRoot != null){
        return containshelper(obj, this.myRoot);
    }
    return false;

}

public static boolean containshelper(Comparable comp, TreeNode t){
    boolean flag = true;
    int x = comp.compareTo(t.myItem);
    if (x < 0 && t.myLeft != null){
        containshelper(comp,t.myLeft);
    }
    if (x > 0 && t.myRight != null){
        containshelper(comp,t.myRight);
    }
    if (x == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public void add(Comparable key) {
    if (!this.contains(key)){
        if (this.myRoot != null){
            add(myRoot, key);
        }
        System.out.print("Getting Here ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("Tree already contains item");
    }
}

private static TreeNode add(TreeNode t, Comparable key) {

    if (((Comparable) t.myItem).compareTo(key) < 0 && t.myLeft != null){
        add(t.myLeft,key);

    }
    if(((Comparable) t.myItem).compareTo(key) > 0 && t.myRight != null ) {
        add(t.myRight,key);

    }
    if (((Comparable) t.myItem).compareTo(key) < 0 && t.myLeft == null){
        TreeNode q = new TreeNode(key);
        t.myLeft = q;

    }
    if (((Comparable) t.myItem).compareTo(key) > 0 && t.myRight == null ){
        TreeNode w = new TreeNode(key);
        t.myRight = w;

    }
    return t;
}
}
```

And here is the TreeNode class (contained within BinaryTree):

```
    public static class TreeNode {

    public Object myItem;
    public TreeNode myLeft;
    public TreeNode myRight;
    public int size;

    public TreeNode (Object obj) {
        size = size(this);
        myItem = obj;
        myLeft = myRight = null;
    }
    public int size(TreeNode t) { 
        return(sizehelper(t)); 
    }
    private int sizehelper(TreeNode node) { 
        if (node == null){ 
            return(0); 
        }
        else { 
            return(size(node.myLeft) + 1 + size(node.myRight)); 
        } 
    }


    public TreeNode (Object obj, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
        myItem = obj;
        myLeft = left;
        myRight = right;
    }
}
}
```

I am pretty sure my contains() methord works, but for the life of of me I can't figure out why add() won't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't observe any error(s) in `add`. What does make you say `add` is not working?

Comment: Besides, in method `containsHelper` you are comparing the parameter with `TreeNode.myItem` which is of type `object` rather than being of type `Comparable`

Comment: Every time I run the Junit test for add() it fails, but works for contains(). I also cast that object to a Comparable, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: This might make more sense on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. And be sure to explain in more detail what trouble you're having - it's really hard to diagnose "add() won't work" and "it still doesn't work"; take the time to explain what you're seeing, what you expect, and what you've tried so far, and you'll get better feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in `containsHelper`

```
public static boolean containshelper(Comparable comp, TreeNode t){

    // TreeNode.myItem should be declared of type `Comparable` instead of `Object`
    int x = comp.compareTo(t.myItem);
    if (x < 0 && t.myLeft != null){
        return containshelper(comp,t.myLeft); // where does result of this call go? We must return the result !!
    }
    if (x > 0 && t.myRight != null){
        return containshelper(comp,t.myRight); // this too ?
    }
    if (x == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The same wrongs here, too:

```
private static TreeNode add(TreeNode t, Comparable key) {

if (t.myItem.compareTo(key) < 0 && t.myLeft != null){
    t = add(t.myLeft,key); // where does returned result go?
}
else if (t.myItem.compareTo(key) > 0 && t.myRight != null ) {
    t = add(t.myRight,key);
}
else if (t.myItem.compareTo(key) < 0 && t.myLeft == null){
    TreeNode q = new TreeNode(key);
    t.myLeft = q;
}
else if (t.myItem.compareTo(key) > 0 && t.myRight == null ){
    TreeNode w = new TreeNode(key);
    t.myRight = w;
}
return t;
}
```

You should declare `TreeNode.myItem` of type `Comparable`, to force every class want to fit in your binary search to provide `compareTo` method. This is better than casting the object into `Comparable`, since the object may be NOT implementing `Comparable`, and then will cause runtime-error